# Sql to button.text

Tags: c#

I want to send from sql on two buttons.

How Can i make this two codes in one?
 Should i use Parameters?

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from category where 
categoryid='1'", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
while (read.Read())
{
    button2.Text = (read["categorydescription"].ToString());
}
read.Close();


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from category where
categoryid='2'", con);
SqlDataReader reads = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reads.Read())
{
    button3.Text = (reads["categorydescription"].ToString());
}
read.Close();
{
```

Comment: you do not need an opening and closing `( )` in this line btw 
`(read["categorydescription"].ToString());` and yes you should use parameters when using dynamic sql also you can convert the code into using a stored procedure . how many records does the `select query` return? if you are returning a single record.. then change the `select statement` to the following `Select categorydescription frm category where category id = 1.ToString()` no need to select everything when you are only trying to assign the `categorydescription` to a textbox field

Comment: I have about 10 buttons and i want each one to take the name from the same column but from different categoryid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it more efficient with one SQL query:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from category where categoryid='1' OR categoryid='2'", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
while (read.Read())
{
   if(read["categoryid"].ToString() == "1")
   {
        button2.Text = (read["categorydescription"].ToString());
   }
   else if(read["categoryid"].ToString() == "2")
   {
       button3.Text = (reads["categorydescription"].ToString());
   }
}
read.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you Sir that was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @DmO no problem, please vote up and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what framework you're working in, I can only assume you're writing in WinForms or WPF.  If that is the case, when you click on a button you will have `object sender` as one of the parameters in the method call. This is the button you clicked. You can cast it to a button and use an `if` block to determine which button was clicked and make decisions based on that.

```
if (((Button)sender).Name == "MyButton")
// Do stuff here
```